# What directory permissions does Apigility require?

Tags: linux, vagrant, laminas-api-tools

I realise that the Apigility UI requires write access to the /modules directory and /config directory.  My question is, what permissions does it require to the sub-directories that it creates?

In my case, it creates sub-directories (such as /module/myapi) with 755.  My web server user does not own the file structure or belong to the relevant group, so it can't write to the directories it has created.  I think that might be causing the errors I am getting.

Under normal circumstances I would just modify the users, groups and permissions to whatever I wanted.  In this case, however, I am using Vagrant and the permissions on my synched directories are under control of the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only answer the last part

> Under normal circumstances I would just modify the users, groups and
>   permissions to whatever I wanted. In this case, however, I am using
>   Vagrant and the permissions on my synched directories are under
>   control of the host.

you can still manage that from Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "apigility_path/modules", "/modules", owner: "web", group: "web"
```

This will create the folder on the host with the correct user/group

you can also add granularity for permission if needed using the `mount_options` property:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "apigility_path/modules", "/modules", owner: "web", group: "web", :mount_options => ["dmode=755","fmode=755"]
```